# Ember Correct way to build computed property for an array or arrays

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Demonstration at https://ember-twiddle.com/e32e95aef1619a9839b4

I'm trying to build a computed property that depends on items within an array or arrays.  Logically this could be done with array1.@each.array2.[] but the documentation is clear that is not valid syntax and results in a warning even though it works.

The warning and guide both tell me to create an interim computed property to bridge this gap, but I can't logically see how to create the property and not run into the exact same problem.

Comment: Doesn't `'groups.@each.users'` work?

Comment: Wow.  That works!  But why?  If I specify users without  [ ] how does ember know to watch the enumerable for changes?